# How should I maintain session on server side in Hapi.js?

Tags: session, server-side, hapi.js

I wish to maintain session data on the server side in hapi.js without storing the cookies in the browser.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: We have two different client applications accessing the same server. We would like to make it so that if a user signs in through one application if they access the other (on the same browser), they would automatically be signed in.
Is this possible?